# Error when comparing strings with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

I am doing this code and it is giving me this error

```
src/app/home/home.page.ts:16:11 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

16   if (this.nome == "") {
             ~
src/app/home/home.page.ts:16:17 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

16   if (this.nome == "") {
                   ~~
src/app/home/home.page.ts:16:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

16   if (this.nome == "") {
                        ~
src/app/home/home.page.ts:19:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

```
export class HomePage {

    inscricao = "São Bernardo";
    nome;
    nomeInvalido;

    constructor() {}

    if (this.nome == "") {
        this.nomeInvalido = true;
    }
  }

<ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nome" name="nome" required></ion-input>
    <small *ngIf="nomeInvalido ? true : false">Este campo é obrigatório!</small>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Please don't ask for help with typo mistakes in the source code. These questions are off topic here, because it doesn't help anyone else. Double check your source code for proper syntax. I would rather you waste hours trying to find where it is and learn something from it, then waste people's time here trying to spot it for you.

Comment: there isn't typo, just I figured out the if must be outside the class

Answer (score 0):

Put your if condition inside of `constructor` or if you are implementing `ngOnInit`, you can put your if condition in that also

like

```
constructor() {
    if (this.nome == "") {
        this.nomeInvalido = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write a statement inside the class body, outside a function. That is not valid, only field and method declarations are allowed here.
Try to move the 3 lines of the if block inside the constructor, or inside a method and call the method from within your constructor.

Comment: please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.